# Count the amount of happy numbers in a given range

Tags: java

As an assignment I need to count the amount of happy numbers in a given range. I do not know how to insert the range, so far I have got this:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String wrd = scan.nextLine().trim();
    String wrd2 = scan.nextLine().trim();

    int nieuwnummer = Integer.parseInt(wrd);
    int nieuwnummer2 = Integer.parseInt(wrd2);
    
    Set<Integer> numbers = new HashSet<Integer>();
        while(numbers.add(nieuwnummer)){     
            nieuwnummer2 = 0;
            while(nieuwnummer>0) {
                nieuwnummer2 += (nieuwnummer % 10)*(nieuwnummer % 10); 
                nieuwnummer /=10;
            }
            nieuwnummer = nieuwnummer2;
        }
      
    
  }
}
```

Here, 'nieuwnummer' should be the lower limit and 'nieuwnummer2' should be the upper limit. But when I click run they don't act as limits. The program can distinguish happy numbers, so now it just needs a range and a counter. Please help.

Comment: Can't you use a `for` loop instead of a `while` and use the given limits as *from* and *to*, like `for (int i = nieuwenummer; i <= nieuwenummer2; i++)` and put the logic inside the body of that loop? By the way, what is the `Set` `numbers` doing in your code? Do you need it?

Comment: The only thing left after implementing the changes suggested by deHaar is to add a separate variable that counts up whenever you find a happy number within that range, and to print that number when you've finished searching the specified range.

Comment: What do you mean by "put the logic inside the body of the loop"? I haven't been coding for long so I don't really understand. Do you mean like this: 
```
for (int i = nieuwnummer; i <= nieuwnummer2; i++ (nieuwnummer>0) {
                nieuwnummer2 += (nieuwnummer % 10)*(nieuwnummer % 10); 
                nieuwnummer /=10;)
```
And how does this create a range? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `for (int i = nieuwnummer; i <= nieuwnummer2; i++) { *Logic goes here* }*` is what deHaar meant. The way this loop works is that it will continue executing the code in the segment *Logic goes here* until the condition is no longer true. In this case you have a counter (`int i`), which is set to your first number (`nieuwnummer`), thus marking the beginning of your range. The loop continues until `i` is greater than `nieuwnummer2`, while always counting `i` up by one for each iteration of the loop (specified by `i++`). Thus, `nieuwnummer2` is used to limit your range.

Comment: I'd highly suggest reading up on loops, for-loops specifically. Unfortunately I'm currently unable to find a good post on Stackoverflow pertaining this matter, but there's a somewhat clear explanation to be found on wikipedia. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what your code could look like (still missing the actual logic to check for happy numbers):

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputLowerRange = scan.nextLine().trim();
        String inputUpperRange = scan.nextLine().trim();

        int lowerRange = Integer.parseInt(inputLowerRange);
        int upperRange = Integer.parseInt(inputUpperRange);
       
        int counter = 0;

        for (int i = lowerRange; i <= upperRange; i++) {
            //Test here, if the current number (i) satisfies the conditions of a happy number
            //If that is the case, add 1 to the variable counter
            
        }
        System.out.println("The number of happy numbers found in the range of " + inputLowerRange + " to " + inputUpperRange + " is: " + counter);
    }
}
```

The reason why it's set up using a `for`-loop is that we go over each number within the specified range. If we have a lower limit of 20 and an upper limit of, say, 25, we're starting out with `i == 20`. We're going to traverse the `for`-loop a total of 6 times (20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25), and the current number is saved in the variable `i`.

This is useful in cases where you do not simply want the number of occurences, but the actual happy numbers as well. In such a case one could simply modify the above code to make it look like this:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputLowerRange = scan.nextLine().trim();
        String inputUpperRange = scan.nextLine().trim();

        int lowerRange = Integer.parseInt(inputLowerRange);
        int upperRange = Integer.parseInt(inputUpperRange);
       
        List<Integer> happyNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i = lowerRange; i <= upperRange; i++) {
            //Test here, if the current number (i) satisfies the conditions of a happy number
            //If that is the case, add the happy number to the list, like so:
            //happyNumbers.add(i);
        }
        System.out.println("The number of happy numbers found in the range of " + inputLowerRange + " to " + inputUpperRange + " is: " + happyNumbers.size());
    }
}
```

Please note that one should always try to make variable names as descriptive as possible, while keeping it short. A string variable name "wrd1" tells me nothing about the content of that variable besides what I can already defer from the data type (string).